# Connecting to postgres works with python bot not in node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I am trying to connect to my `postgres docker-container` using the following code:

```
const { Pool, Client } = require("pg");
var conString = "postgres://postgres:rootuser@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres";
const pool = new Pool({
  conString,
});
console.log("--------------- first ---------------")
pool.query("SELECT NOW()", (err, res) => {
  console.log("--------------- second ---------------")
  console.log(err, res);
  pool.end();
});
console.log("--------------- third ---------------")

const client = new Client({
  conString,
});
client.connect().then((client) => {
  client.query("SELECT NOW()", (err, res) => {
    console.log("--------------- fourth ---------------")
    console.log(err, res);
    client.end();
  });
});
```

This does not work at all. The output i get:

`--------------- first ---------------`
`--------------- third ---------------`

While executing this `python` script works:

```
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                  password="rootuser",
                                  host="localhost",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="postgres")


    cursor = connection.cursor()

    print(connection.get_dsn_parameters(), "\n")

    cursor.execute("SELECT NOW()")

    # Fetch result
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()

    print("now: ", record, "\n")

except (Exception, Error) as error:
    print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
finally:
    if (connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

I am so confused. Maybe something with `docker` and `node`?

- Host: Mac M1
- pg version: 8.0.3
- node version: v18.7.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: I thought it was `postgresql://...` not `postgres://...`

Comment: still not working unfortunately

Comment: often there may be troubles with `localhost` vs `127.0.0.1`, try to change those as well

Comment: I already tried this

Comment: the only similar thing I remember that is close to "No output, no error, nothing." was when node changed the default state for net.Socket https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2170#issuecomment-617556848. Funnily, this was fixed in the exact version you have. Maybe update to lates v8.7.x? And try other node versions with `nvm`

Comment: Also, if you're seeing literally no output, add some console.log statements at the root level to verify your code is even trying to execute (and/or share how you're invoking the script).

Comment: I updated the code example by some `console.log()` only `first`and `third` is being printed.

Comment: @EvgeniyChekan my god, thank you. Hate these kind of errors..

Comment: @greterpiffin glad to help, we spent a couple of days on this creature back in the day :D

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to @EvgeniyChekan , I was able to resolve this bug, it's related to the node-version. I have now changed it, depending on [this](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2170#issuecomment-617556848) bug.